# Ping from a public EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ping

I created a public instance and attached a security group in it.
[image]

The SSH is for connecting to the EC2 instance itself through the management console, and the ICMP is for the ping request.

However, I am getting the following error.

```
enter code here[ec2-user@<IP_OF_THE_EC2_INTANCE> ~]$ ping google.com
 ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I am confused what you are asking. Are you saying that you can successfully SSH into the instance? And that your only problem is that you can't ping an external URL? What is the configuration of the **Outbound rules on the security group** attached to the instance? It should permit All Outbound traffic.

Answer (score 1):

The error `google.com: Name or service not known` basically means that the ec2 instance cannot resolve the google url.
You need to check your DNS configuration.

You could also try to ping an IP, instead of a URL to see if you have a network connectivity issue as well. Try pinging some famous IP, like:
`ping 8.8.8.8`
If that also fails as well, you should try to fix the network problem first.